# Using forEach or a forLoop, how do you run the callback on each element with a 1second delay between each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to run a function every second for each element in an array, however I have been unable to figure it out. My code is below.

Basically I'm wanting to run this.activeButton() every second for each element in the array. It was suggested to wrap this.activeButton() to run every second, however it simply runs the function on all of the elements in the array after 1 second instead of running the function every second for EACH element in the array.

```
  drawComputerMoves(moves) {
    moves.forEach((move) => {    
      let buttonRef = 0;
      switch (move) {
        case 1:
          buttonRef = 'greenBtn'
          break;
        case 2:
          buttonRef = 'redBtn'
          break;
        case 3:
          buttonRef = 'blueBtn'
          break;
        case 4:
          buttonRef = 'yellowBtn'
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      setTimeout(() => this.activeButton(buttonRef), 1000)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` function.

Comment: Wrap it in `setInterval`.

Comment: Also, instead of that whole `switch`, you can use `let buttonRef = ['greenBtn','redBtn','blueBtn','yellowBtn'][move-1] || 0`

Comment: Hey @Cerberus, what technique or method is this? It looks more simple, however I do not understand it. Cheers.

Comment: @Nims, the first part is just an array, where you take the element at index `move-1`. For example:  `['a','b','c'][1]` returns `b`. The `|| 0` is for the `default` case, where the `move` is out of range of the array. Then the `[][]` returns undefined, `|| 0` makes sure a default value is returned. For example:  `['a','b','c'][7] || 0`.

Comment: @Cerberus, thanks!

Comment: BTW which part of the above function am a wrapping with setInterval?

Comment: @Walk, which part should I be wrap with setInterval? Thanks :)

Comment: @Nims `this.activeButton(buttonRef)`, so it will look like `setInterval(() => { this.activeButton(buttonRef) }, 1000);`